# Generic Linq Find method for Repository

Tags: c#, linq, repository-pattern

I have an application using the Repository pattern to abstract how data is retrieved. I plan on using a web service for retrieving the data, but during development will just mock it out. However, I am stuck on how to get a find method working. I have the following so far, but I am not sure that `query.Compile()` is the right thing to be doing (no examples I have found do that). I get a compiler error saying there is no overload for Linq's Where method that takes a `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`. Here is where I am at so far:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Customer>> FindAsync(Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> query)
{
    var allCustomers = await GetAllAsync(true);

    return allCustomers.Where(query.Compile());
}
```

At some point, I would like to figure out how to avoid retrieving all customers and then applying the expression also, but am not sure how I can pass the expression to a REST webservice so the filtering can happen at the data access layer.

Comment: If you are getting data from WebService, you need to implement own LINQ provider in order to use `IQueryable`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb546158%28v=vs.110%29.aspx - assuming that WebService allows to filter data.

Comment: This does compile. Why are you using an `Expression` and not simply a `Func<Customer, bool>`?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I suppose that OP want's to do filtering at WebService side - when using `IEnumerable` with `Func` all data are fetched and filtered at client side. He needs to implement own LINQ provider - when WebService supports querying API.

Comment: @pwas Right, i missed that. thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't worked out the web services yet (considering exposing oData or using business layer for API that interacts with oData data layer using WCF). Is there a Linq provider already for oData?

Comment: @Mike Unfortunately not - LINQ provider is usually prepared for specified, concrete service. Here is my sample: http://1drv.ms/W2tbVf I've preapred sample fake service and implement LINQ provider for `Take` and `Where`. I've also recorded clip with explanation but unfortunately the language record is not english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementations of Repository pattern I've seen generally look like this (using Entity Framework):

```
public class Repository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly DbSet<T> _queryableBase;

    public Repository(DbSet<T> queryableBase)
    {
        _queryableBase = queryableBase;
    }

    public T Select(IFilter<T> filterClass)
    {
        return filterClass.Filter(_queryableBase.AsQueryable()).First();
    }
    public IEnumerable<T> SelectMany(IFilter<T> filterClass)
    {
        return filterClass.Filter(_queryableBase.AsQueryable());
    }

    public void Delete(T item)
    {
        _queryableBase.Remove(item);
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        _queryableBase.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Then the filter object:

```
public interface IFilter<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> Filter(IEnumerable<T> queryableBase);
}
```

Example filtering implementation:

```
class FilterChris : IFilter<ATestObject>
{
    public IEnumerable<ATestObject> Filter(IEnumerable<ATestObject> queryableBase)
    {
        return queryableBase.Where(o => o.FirstName == "Chris");
    }
}

public class ATestObject
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Note that filters can chain.

Answer (score 1):

> At some point, I would like to figure out how to avoid retrieving all
>   customers and then applying the expression also, but am not sure how I
>   can pass the expression to a REST webservice so the filtering can
>   happen at the data access layer.

Assuming your client app is written in C# you could use breeze-sharp:

http://www.breezejs.com/breeze-sharp-documentation/query-examples#whereSimple

> BreezeSharp communicates with any service that speaks HTTP and JSON.
>   Are you serving data with Web API, OData or MVC backed by Entity
>   Framework in front of SQL Server? Breeze has a great out-of-the-box
>   story.

BreezeSharp would allow you to write code like this on the client:

```
var query3 = query1.Where(td => !td.IsArchived && !td.IsDone);
var activeTodos = awaitManager.ExecuteQuery(query3);
```